# Add to a list in Shiny

Tags: r, list, global, shiny

I want to define a list that a user may update through doing certain actions. I did this:

```
runApp(list(
  ui=fluidPage(
    h1('Example')
    ,textInput('txt','','Text')
    ,actionButton('add','add')
    ,verbatimTextOutput('list')
    )#ui

  ,server=function(input,output,session) {
    s.list<-reactive(isolate(d.list()))
    d.list<-reactive({if (input$add == 0)   return()
                      isolate({
      list(input$txt,unlist(s.list()))
                      })#iso
    })#rea
    output$list<-renderPrint({
      list(unlist(d.list()))
    })#list
  }#server

  ))#ruanApp
```

But the list updates infinitely many times, does anyone know a way to make this work?

Comment: I would +1 again if I could for the reproducible question which is usually lacking when `shiny` is involved

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `reactiveValues`

```
require(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui=fluidPage(
    h1('Example')
    ,textInput('txt','','Text')
    ,actionButton('add','add')
    ,verbatimTextOutput('list')
  )

  ,server=function(input,output,session) {
    myValues <- reactiveValues()
    observe({
      if(input$add > 0){
        myValues$dList <- c(isolate(myValues$dList), isolate(input$txt))
      }
    })
    output$list<-renderPrint({
      myValues$dList
    })
  }

))
```

[image: shiny app]

Comment: Note that it really should be `c(isolate(myValues$dList), isolate(input$txt))` so that the list doesn't automatically append the new text input when you enter it, before hitting the button.