# Shiny: how to input a list of text strings that are delimited with double-quotes (")

Tags: r, text, shiny, textinput

I am running into a problem with text inputs. The default seems to be that the textInput() function outputs the text with "" around it. I am trying to feed multiple words into textInput(), with a "" around each word. For example:

instead of outputting test1,test2,test3 as: "test1,test2,test3", 
I want "test1","test2","test3"

I tried using a combination of cat() and paste() with \ to workaround it, but it does not seem that the renderDatatable() function accepts that.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
    ui<- fluidPage(
    textInput(inputId = "words",
              label = "Enter search terms, separated by commas", 
              value = ""),
    titlePanel("List of Claims"),
    fluidRow(
        dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )

)
server <- function(input,output){

    reactivedata <- reactive({
        input$words
    })

    output$table <- renderDataTable({
        inputtext<-function(x) {paste(eval(parse(text=input$words)))}
        claiminfo2$xxtotal <-rowSums(claiminfo2[,inputtext(X)])
        claiminfo3 <- claiminfo2[,c(1,length(claiminfo2))]
        claiminfo4 <- subset(claiminfo3,claiminfo3[,2] >0)
        claiminfo4
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

claiminfo2 is a document term matrix with words as column headings. I am trying to have it so that the user inputs words, and then the app searches for those columns by `claiminfo2[,c(words)]`. However, instead of getting 
`claiminfo2[,c("word1","word2")]`, I am getting
`claiminfo2[,c("word1 , word2")]` which won't work

Comment: You should add a small reproducible example (a small shiny app) so that we can test solutions.

Comment: is that good enough?

Comment: you can see this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874674/add-to-a-list-in-shiny) have a excelente Asier to your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maybe use `strsplit` in your `server.R` to create the vector of words to use for subsetting your dataframe. Here is an example (the `ui.R` is unchanged):

```
claiminfo2 <- data.frame(a=letters[1:4],b=letters[5:8],d=letters[9:12])
    server <- function(input,output){

            output$table <- renderDataTable({
                    claiminfo2[,unlist(strsplit(input$words,",")),drop=FALSE]

            })
```

Another options is to use a `selectize` input, this will give the user suggestions of what columns are in your data frame. Here's an example:

```
library(shiny)
claiminfo2 <- data.frame(a=letters[1:4],b=letters[5:8],d=letters[9:12])

ui<- fluidPage(
        titlePanel("List of Claims"),
        fluidRow(
                dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
        ),
        selectInput(inputId = "words",
                       label = "Enter search terms, separated by commas",
                       choices=colnames(claiminfo2), multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE)

)
server <- function(input,output){

        output$table <- renderDataTable({
                if(!is.null(input$words)){ 
                claiminfo2[,unlist(strsplit(input$words,",")),drop=FALSE]
                }

        })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```